# How do you make the Application window open when the dock icon is clicked?

Tags: cocoa

I'm surprised this doesn't happen automatically, but I would like my applications window to open automatically when the Dock icon is clicked.

Just to clarify, when i open the app, the window automatically opens, but when I click the cross for the window but leave the App running, the window won't open when i click the dock icon.

Comment: This does happen automatically. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Implement `- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag` in your app delegate. Check the documentation for the details of the return value.

Document based apps and non-document based apps behave slightly differently. If there are no open windows when the dock icon of a document based app is clicked then it will create a new document. If there are no open windows when the dock icon of a non-document based app is clicked then it will do nothing.

Comment: how about case when I have two opened windows, the main window and the child window. The child window has a focus. I need to set the main window focused after click on the dock icon.

Answer (score 15):

```
- (BOOL)applicationShouldHandleReopen:(NSApplication *)theApplication hasVisibleWindows:(BOOL)flag
{
    if (flag) {
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
       [YourWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];// Window that you want open while click on dock app icon
        return YES;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This is what I'm doing to get the main window of a non-document based app back to screen once it has been closed. I know this might not be the right way to do it but It's working for me so far.

Implemented this on the AppDelegate, window is defined as instance variable of the same object.

```
- (BOOL) applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    [window makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
    return NO;
}
```

If anyone has a better solution please reply. Thanks!

Comment: I was trying to figure this out as well (how to display another window for a document based app) and this worked perfect!

Answer (score 11):

As others pointed, using `applicationShouldHandleReopen` method for reopening closed windows in non-document apps is the right way. The only change I want to add is a more flexible way to check what window must be re-displayed, by iterating through the `NSApplication`'s list of visible and invisible `.windows` and checking for the required window.

```
func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {

    if flag == false {

        for window in sender.windows {

            if (window.delegate?.isKind(of: WelcomeWindowController.self)) == true {
                window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(self)
            }
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

**Appendix**

a) If window was hidden then it will be showed automatically when user will click on app's Dock icon, so no need to implement `applicationShouldHandleReopen` method.

b) Checked *"Release when closed"* option doesn't affect in any way the above behaviour.

Comment: I ended up here while trying to fix an issue with SwiftUI apps on macOS where clicking the dock doesn't launch a miniaturized window, but this method doesn't get called if you're using the SwiftUI lifecycle, example here: https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/u5srtt/applicationshouldhandlereopen_is_not_called_in

If anyone has any idea on what to do here, I'd love to hear about it.

Answer (score 4):

A document based application will automatically open a new untitled document when the app becomes active, so I am assuming you are referring to a non-document based app.

Implement the [applicationDidBecomeActive:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/applicationDidBecomeActive:) method in your application delegate and open/show the window.

Edit:

Some information on [Delegates](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18).

Some information on [Opening and Closing Windows](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Tasks/OpeningClosingWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000226-CJBCCCEF) and the [NSWindow](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) API

Comment: I don't understand how I can implement the applicationDidBecomeActive: method. Can you give me a code snipped/example/

Comment: Where is the checkbox for hide on load in IB?

Comment: @Joshua - I'm sorry, it's the exact opposite. If you select the inspector for the Window in the nib file, make sure that "Visible at Launch" is checked.

Comment: @Jason Check the first post, It opens fine when you first open it, but when you click the cross, but not close the App, and then click the dock icon the window does not automatically open.

Comment: How is that going to help? Can you tell me how to make the window open again after it's been closed (not the app, the window) by clicking the dock icon?

Comment: It works if you hide the window but not if you close the window. Which I think is because Cocoa is releasing the window if you close it. But the obvious checkbox in IB doesn't help. I'm doing more research.

Answer (score 3):

A solutions to add to the accepted answer:

With the accepted answer the reopened window did not react to mouse events anymore.

When using the accepted answer you also have to make sure to uncheck "Release when closed" in the Attributes Inspector of the window in IB. This fixes the unresponsive window problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/706772?answerId=715063022#715063022

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) 
{
    NSApplication.shared.delegate = self
}

func applicationShouldHandleReopen(_ sender: NSApplication, hasVisibleWindows flag: Bool) -> Bool {
     //Now is working
    return true
}
```